# ResponseFormat returns 0 byte

Tags: c#, json, rest

I want to make a REST web service with JSON return format. actually it is working for a simple string return type, but when I have a custom type as the return value I receive 0 byte.

if I change the ResponseFormat to XML, it works fine

thanks for any help!

EDIT - adding sample

interface:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="WebGetTry/{param1}/{param2}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
WebGetType WebGetTry(string param1, string param2);
```

implement:

```
public WebGetType WebGetTry(string param1, string param2) {
  return new WebGetType();
}
```

after that my test is simple calling the address from IE. returning Page Cannot be displayed error

Comment: Please show us some code that you use for return the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the implementation of your JSON endpoint. please check your web.config and add this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Comment: thanks, but this was not really a solution, i still didn't have json result

i think the best is if you download, the WCF REST project template [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) or you start with Web API